# Power BI creating table/report from multiple tables

Tags: powerbi

I am new to power bi and trying to create table/report that pulls data from three different tables.

I have one table "Conversion":  with columns like: conversion_id, date_converted,channel, revenue and other columns and measures

Second table "Qualification": Qualification_id, date_qualified, channel, revenue and other columns and measures

Third table "Spend" : Date, channel, Spend and other columns and measures

Qualification_id is same as  conversion_id but it could have different dates  (dates for id that got converted and qualified many times differ) and not every id that converts qualifies.

I want to display sum(spend) , count of qualifications , count of conversion and qualification rate (qualification/conversion) grouped by date and channel in one report

[image]

There were no relationships detected in amongst these three tables. Please note that the date values are not unique. I am looking into creating star schema and calculated table but since I am super new to this I am struggling to create this view. Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: I'm afraid this question is rather too broad and unclear to be likely to get good responses. What is the particular step you are having trouble with?

Comment: Hey @AlexisOlson -  I am struggling with creating a relation among these three tables so that I can get a summarized view of count of conversion , count of qualification and spend by date, channel etc or any other common dimensions present in these tables in one table/report.

Answer (score 0):

If I have understood correctly ,conversion_id & date_converted will match Qualification_id & Qualification_date ,if the Conversion_ID qualifies.
If this is the case maybe you can create a new Column in both the tables which will be a concatenation as below and join those two columns like

```
Qualification_Key = Qualification_id & "-" & Qualification_date 
Conversion_Key = Conversion_ID  & "-" & date_converted
```

Comment: Hi, Conversion_id is a super set of qualification_id but date_created and date qualified may or may not be the same